# Tips for reducing size of .dylib and .so

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, build

I'm trying to compile the SDK manually, but the generated .dylibs and .so are over 70mb in size:

```
➜  lib ✗ pwd
/Users/gond/opencv/build/lib
➜  lib ✗ du -h .
 71M
```

This is the command I'm using:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON \
       -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

Is there any way to reduce the size? Ultimately I'd like to compile opencv for Android, but 70mb worth of libraries would be way too big for a reasonable app.

Any thought appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here's a list of the largest 10 libraries generated using the above command:

```
38M libopencv_imgproc.3.4.0.dylib
13M libopencv_core.3.4.0.dylib
4.1M libopencv_dnn.3.4.0.dylib
3.1M cv2.so
2.9M libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.0.dylib
1.9M libopencv_calib3d.3.4.0.dylib
1.3M libopencv_ts.a
1.2M libopencv_java340.dylib
916K libopencv_photo.3.4.0.dylib
```

Here's the list of the largest 10 using the Android option:

```
40M libopencv_java3.so
6.0M libopencv_imgproc.a
5.5M libopencv_core.a
2.5M libopencv_ximgproc.a
2.4M libopencv_calib3d.a
1.6M libopencv_ts.a
1.5M libopencv_photo.a
1.5M libopencv_ml.a
1.3M libopencv_features2d.a
```

Strangely, `libopencv_imgproc.3.4.0.dylib` is 38mb yet `libopencv_imgproc.a` is 13mb. Are there ways to leave out 'submodules'? For instance, is there a way to leave out motion analysis, object detection but keep ColorMaps?

Comment: Unless you're built the monolithic `world` variant, you have a library per OpenCV module. So figure out which ones you actually need (based on what functionality you're using) -- that's likely to be a much smaller subset.

Comment: @DanMašek Using the above command, the largest library is the `.dylib` for `improc` which is 38mb. Can it be stripped down somehow? Also, if I build using Android options, the resulting `libopencv_java3.so` is 40mb on its own. There're other `.a` libraries, but the biggest is around 6mb.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MINSIZEREL ...
```

try to `strip` everything and use `upx` also...

Comment: I thought stripping won't do anything. the bindings ensure that everything they reference stays. I'd prefer not to use `MINSIZEREL` since speed isn't optimised.